# How to get vertical lines in a 3D scatter plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure

I have three matrices x, y, z which are plotted via scatter3 in matlab. However I also need vertical lines dropping from every point in the graph for better visualization.

Using matlab 2017a, implemented 3D scatter plot in matlab.

```
enter code here
clc;
figure
x = [0,0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,10];
y = [0,10,20,30,40,-10,0,10,20,30];
z = [46,52,51,59,53,85,56,87,86,88];
scatter3(x, y, z, 30, 'filled')
```

Comment: Simply draw lines using `plot3`. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[SardarUsama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698672/sardar-usama) pointed out, `plot3` should do the trick. Code could be more compact but kept it as is for clarity.

[image: Vertical lines on 3d scatter plot]

```
% MATLAB R2017a   
x = [0,0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,10];
y = [0,10,20,30,40,-10,0,10,20,30];
z = [46,52,51,59,53,85,56,87,86,88];

figure
scatter3(x, y, z, 30, 'filled')  % scatter plot (3D)
zRng = zlim;
hold on
for k = 1:length(x)
    xL = [x(k) x(k)];
    yL = [y(k) y(k)];
    zL = [zRng(1) z(k)];
    plot3(xL,yL,zL,'r-')         % plot vertical line (3D)
end
```

Comment: **Future visitors** should see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56172633/8239061) using [`stem3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem3.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the built in function [`stem`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html), which is doing exactly that.

The minor trick is that you cannot pass the `z` coordinates in the shorthand form `stem(x,y,z)`, but the graphic object still accept `z` data, you just have to send them as additional parameter.

The nice part of it is you do not need a loop ;-)

```
x = [0,0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,10];
y = [0,10,20,30,40,-10,0,10,20,30];
z = [46,52,51,59,53,85,56,87,86,88];

hp = stem(x,y,'filled','ZData',z) ;
```

Or as *Gnovice* nicely pointed out, even easier to use the `stem3` function which accept `z` data directly:

```
hp = stem3(x,y,z,'filled') ;
```

Both example above will produce:

[image]

Comment: Hint: There's actually a [`stem3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem3.html) for this. ;)

Comment: **Future visitors**, this is probably a superior solution for most use cases (+1).